# Reset Mac/Apache web server folder permissions?

Tags: apache, macos, permissions

I've messed up my Apache web server folder settings; what's the CHOWN command I'd use to restore owners & permissions back to the default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my Mac:

`chown -R root:wheel /etc/apache2`